# Accessing JSON object with PHP, Random Object Name

Tags: php, json

I am trying to parse out certain things within the JSON code, but the problem is that the two groups of arrays that have the information in it I need have random names,  here is from the var_dump:

```
array (size=2)
'results' => 
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Phone.5d5b6fef-a2e0-4b08-cfe3-bc7128b776c3.Durable' (length=50)
'dictionary' => 
array (size=3)
  'Person.51f28c76-2993-42d3-8d65-4ea0a66c5e16.Ephemeral' => 
    array (size=8)
      'id' => 
        array (size=5)
          ...
      'type' => null
      'names' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'age_range' => null
      'locations' => null
      'phones' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
      'best_name' => string 'John Smith' (length=15)
      'best_location' => null
  'Location.28dc9041-a0ee-4613-a3b0-65839aa461da.Durable' => 
    array (size=30)
      'id' => 
        array (size=5)
          ...
      'type' => string 'ZipPlus4' (length=8)
      'valid_for' => null
      'legal_entities_at' => null
      'city' => string 'City' (length=8)
      'postal_code' => string '12345' (length=5)
      'zip4' => string '4812' (length=4)
      'state_code' => string 'MO' (length=2)
      'country_code' => string 'US' (length=2)
      'address' => string 'Main St, City, MO 12345-4812' (length=33)
      'house' => null
```

No I am trying to get `best_name` from under the part that starts with Person and `address` under Location.  But when I do:

```
$string = file_get_contents($url);
$json=json_decode($string,true);
var_dump($json);
echo $json['dictionary']['Person']['best_name'];
```

I get `Undefined index: Person` error, because the actual object name for Person is:
`Person.51f28c76-2993-42d3-8d65-4ea0a66c5e16.Ephemeral` which is different every time I do a search.  Is there a way to do this without putting the random generated line in?

Hopefully this makes sense, thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Can you provide the original arrays, please?! :)

Comment: You'll need to loop through `$json['dictionary']` and find the key that begins with 'Person' and then proceed to get `best_name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Person key always starts with the string "Person", than simply do a foreach and check the key which contains this string.

Like:

```
foreach ($json['dictionary'] as $key => $value) {
  if (preg_match('/^Person/', $key)) {
    echo $json['dictionary'][$key]['best_name'];
  }
}
```

Of course this get complicated, if you have multiple keys which start with "Person".

You can do the same with "Location" or any other string you need.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked like a charm.  I cannot mark it is correct though yet:(

Comment: @kingkero Yes, the ".*$" can be left out, but I like to put it there. :) Thanks for the edit anyway.

Comment: @Vaulgatnis You are welcome to rollback. I like my code to be as precise & concise as possible (without losing readability of course) - so I usually remove parts that do nothing (like `.*$`)

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this ... loop through `$json['dictionary']`'s index keys to find something that starts with "Person".

```
$foundIt = false;
foreach (array_keys($json['dictionary']) as $key) {
    if (substr($key,0,6) == 'Person') {
         $foundIt = $key;
         break;
    }
}
if ($foundIt) { echo $json['dictionary'][$foundIt]['best_name']; }
```